# Split a string based on a pattern [YYYY-MM-DD MM:HH:SS]

Tags: python, split, spyder

I have a string which a I loaded from a txt file. I'd like split it using the split() method but based in a patter in the data, which is the date, which is stored like [yyyy-mmm-dd mm-hh-ss].

Is there any way to write this pattern?

Comment: can you please specify, in which particular format you need the string, after splitting

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way here would be to use the `datetime` module. You can use this this way:

```
import datetime

my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-01-16 07-17-00", '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')

# prints the date's year
print(my_date.year)

# prints the date's month
print(my_date.month)

# prints the date's day
print(my_date.day)

# prints the date's hour
print(my_date.hour)

# prints the date's minute
print(my_date.minute)

# prints the date's second
print(my_date.second)
```

**Output**

```
2021
1
16
7
17
0
```